# Haskell Most Efficient Mutable Data Structure

Tags: arrays, performance, haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I am writing a game program in Haskell that currently has a data type like this

```
data World = World {
    worldPlayer :: !(IORef GameObject),
    worldEntities :: ![IORef GameObject],
    ...
}
```

Each update, the following update is written to the player `IORef`:

```
updatePlayer :: GameObject -> [IORef GameObject] -> IO GameObject
```

In this function, it checks for collision on each object, then moves the player.
But I would like the updatePlayer function to be pure, so I need to use a different data structure.

The most obvious idea is to take the `[IORef GameObject]` from the world and transform it into an `IO [GameObject]` by calling `readIORef` on each index. But this would be very inefficient.

Another possible way I found to do this is using `Data.Vector.MVector` and `Data.Vector.Generic.unsafeUnfreeze` and `unsafeFreeze`, which have `O(1)` performance to do `worldEntities :: !(MVector (PrimState IO) GameObject)`. The problem is that `unsafeUnfreeze` and `unsafeFreeze` only work on certain data types.

I also found `IOArray`, so I could use `IOArray Int GameObject`, but I cannot find a way to convert `IOArray`s into an immutable structure.

Last, I could just do `IORef [GameObject]` or `IORef (Vector GameObject)`, but I am unsure how efficient this would be.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually need a mutable data structure?  Are you sure returning a new data structure each update is not fast enough?

Comment: @TomEllis I think that would be very inefficient, if you mean calculating the whole `World` every update.

Comment: It depends what `GameObject` is precisely.  Returning a new object will certainly be less efficient than mutating, but probably not as much as you think, and it's certainly a lot easier!  It can actually be very fast if little changes between updates and you can share a lot of the old structure.

Comment: @ala-rucnuru is your game implementation using concurrency? If not it's possible you're misunderstanding `IORef`. Maybe you could give a bit more of your game code?

Comment: @jberryman here's my [github](https://github.com/fiendfan1/Haskell-OpenGL/blob/master/Modern/), data is declared in [World.hs](https://github.com/fiendfan1/Haskell-OpenGL/blob/master/Modern/Engine/Core/World.hs), [Player.hs](https://github.com/fiendfan1/Haskell-OpenGL/blob/master/Modern/Engine/Object/Player.hs) contains player updates.

Comment: @ala-rucnuru I didn't look closely but I think your use of mutable state isn't idiomatic; can you articulate why you're using `IORef`s? Note that storing a pure value in an IORef doesn't make it mutable, i.e. in all cases it is going to be less efficient than passing the pure contained value around between functions.

Comment: First of all, you should absolutely make sure if you need to struggle for performance so desperately. Write a mock-up first to find bottlenecks, then think of optimization. Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Just because repetition from another source might enhance the point: The way you're using `IORef`s here is going to be a performance loss, not a gain. Write your code with pure structures first. If benchmarking shows it's too slow, look into making it faster - possibly by introducing mutability in the right places. But where you have it now isn't the right places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) instead of mutable objects, to get "setter-like" behavior. Try that before messing around with mutable state, which is very ugly in Haskell (intentionally ugly, to discourage you from doing it).

(Edit to add: "setter-like" syntax. Lens "setters" still create new references to the "set"ted result, so you still need to sequence your main loop to read from the returned value from the setter, you can't re-read an old (immutable) reference to get an updated value, of course.)

Comment: It's absolutely not true that Haskell deliberately makes things like mutable state ugly in order to discourage their use; that would be a terrible language decision. Mutable state in Haskell is appropriately compartmentalized from pure code, yes, but ST monad code really isn't appreciably uglier than any other imperative language (though I guess that's a pretty subjective topic).